# Add map rule to predefined data style (refer to "value of this data item")

Tags: birt

in our reporting the value of data elements will be rewrited with "-" in the case of Null.

Can I put this mapping rule to the predefined style of the "data" element ? I tried it, but I don't know who to implement the later reference to "The_current_row_value". Has anyone a idea?

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a SQL data source?

Comment: yes. mySQL data source with jdbc driver

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to use an edit tool in the report, use SQL's isnull() to convert null values to whatever value you desire.

[ISNULL (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

If for some reason that does not appeal to you, use a computed column in your BIRT data set, and define the value with Java Script.

Comment: your'e answer is correct. but , I wants to apply this rule on every Birt-data object who use the report and I applied on it this style. i dont know if the answer was enough clear - I wants to use the map feature of the style , but i just not know how to tell Birt "the currect row". if I was in specific table the current value calls ' dataSetRow["row_name"] ' but here its need to be more generic , somethig like ' this.getValue() '